# How to create a list of all pages of lektor project?

Tags: python, templates, model, jinja2, lektor

In a **model** I am using a field of the type *select* to let the user choose a link among all children of the root of my site:

```
[fields.link]
label = Link
type = select
source = site.get('/').children
```

To offer a list of these children in my model I use the following command

```
site.get('/').children
```

in the according **model**.

In the **template** I use the following jina2 code to create a link:

```
<a href="{{ '/' + this.link|url }}">my link</a>
```

This lets the user choose a link-address among all children of *'/'* of my page.
This is limited to children of the root directory. Now I want to expand this functionality to **a list of all created pages available** in my lektor project, but I do not know how to do this.

Is there a possibility to create a list of all pages in my lektor project? (with the limited possibility to use code in a model)